# Is it possible to create Tabulator table without attaching it to the DOM?

Tags: tabulator

From [the quick start](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/quickstart) example I can create Tabulator as:

```
<div id="example-table"></div>
var tabulator =  new Tabulator("#example-table", { ... } )
```

Is it possible to create `tabulator` object without attaching it to the DOM?

If I do `new Tabulator()` or `new Tabulator( '#noelem' )` I get errors:

```
Tabulator Creation Error - Invalid element provided: undefined
Tabulator Creation Error - no element found matching selector:  #noelem
```

The method which creates `Tabulator` does not know the DOM point where this object will be attached

Answer (score 2):

I was tried:

```
    var elTab =  document.createElement("div");
    new Tabulator( elTab, opts ).setData( [ { array: 'with data' }] );
    return elTab.outerHTML;
```

Table is constructed but data is not displayed

**UPD**

[here](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1977#issuecomment-482860830) is official answer why data is not displayed.